# Load New Cards/Information without Resetting View

Tags: ios, objective-c

DraggableViewBackground is essentially a deck of cards. In it, there is a method to remove and load new cards (which involves calling the foursquare API). The call to the foursquare API happens in my ViewController.m file. The code posted below is from the call to foursquare method, specifically for updating.

This is the current transition in my ViewController.m file:

```
                    draggableBackground = [[DraggableViewBackground alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) :venueList];
                    draggableBackground.tag=1;
                    if(obj.tutorial) {
                        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:[self.view viewWithTag:1]];
                    }
                    else{
                        [self.view addSubview:draggableBackground];
                    }
                }
                if (obj.firstGeoLoc){
                    draggableBackground.firstThree.hidden=NO;
                }else{
                    [draggableBackground.firstThree removeFromSuperview];
                }
```

I want while I'm in the middle of a deck, for the next deck to load. However, I don't want to reset the view until I have finished going through my original deck. However, as it originally existed, it calls the API and then resets DraggableViewBackground, so the user is looking at a new set of cards. Now, I want it to call foursquare and thus "load the deck", without showing the new cards until the end of the first deck is reached

Comment: I think we probably need a bit more information to really help you out here ... what exactly do you mean by `loading the next deck` ?

Comment: So, DraggableViewBackground is essentially a deck of cards. In it, there is a method to remove and load new cards (which involves calling the foursquare API). The call to the foursquare API happens in my ViewController.m file. The code posted above is from the call to foursquare method, specifically for updating. However, as it originally existed, it calls the API and then resets DraggableViewBackground, so the user is looking at a new set of cards. Now, I want it to call foursquare and thus "load the deck", without showing the new cards until the end of the first deck is reached.

Comment: You should add these precisions to the original question by editing it instead of making a comment so that people will immediate see them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... so based on your clarification in the comments, it sounds to me like you need to separate the concept of "getting the data", from adding the view to the UI.

You need to organize the code so that you make the API call in the background to retrieve data; then a separate routine to load the UI. This makes it a simple task then to execute the following steps:

1. Load the initial deck
2. Display the UI once the data is returned
3. Immediately kick off the retrieval of the next deck to a local cache.

Since the data is loading on a background thread, the user is free to continue operating ... and then when they move to the next one, you can pull the locally cached data and show them immediately.

It's kind of hard to be specific without seeing more of your code, but in general (and of course YMMV), this is probably how you want to structure things :)